# MySQL index on two columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've tried to create a two-column index on my table this way:

```
CREATE INDEX prod_hash_index ON components(producer_normalized, hash);
```

Which results in not one, but two indexes (when I do `SHOW INDEXES FROM components;`):

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| components |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id                  | A         |     1570231 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| components |          1 | item_num        |            1 | item_num            | A         |     1570231 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| components |          1 | fs_index        |            1 | first_symbol        | A         |         303 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| components |          1 | prod_hash_index |            1 | producer_normalized | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| components |          1 | prod_hash_index |            2 | hash                | A         |     1570231 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

What does it mean? Did MySQL create an additional one-column index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you read in result panel every row, with index name and column in the index.

About prod_has_index you have, first row about producer_normalized column in position one
and another row for has column in position (seq_in_index) 2.

Comment: I missed the meaning of `Seq_in_index` column. Now I understand how to interpret the results of `SHOW INDEXES`. Thanks!